# python memory explodes because of loop

Tags: python, for-loop, gpu, pytorch

```
def compute_linear_gradient_manually(args,model,data_tr,data_te,device):
    N_tr = len(data_tr)
    N_te = len(data_te)
    kernel_tr = torch.zeros(N_tr,N_tr).to(device)
    kernel_te = torch.zeros(N_te,N_tr).to(device)
    for i in range(N_tr):
        grad_tr = compute_layer_gradient(args,model,data_tr[i])
        for j in range(N_tr):
            grad_tr_ = compute_layer_gradient(args,model,data_tr[j])
            kernel_tr[i][j] = torch.mm(grad_tr,grad_tr_.t())
        for k in range(N_te):
            grad_tr_ = compute_layer_gradient(args,model,data_te[k])
            kernel_te[i][k] = torch.mm(grad_tr,grad_tr_.t())
    return kernel_tr,kernel_te

def compute_layer_gradient(args,model,data):
    p = ((torch.mm(data.view(-1,3072),model.weight1)+model.bias1)>0).float()
    weight2_grad = ((torch.mm(data.view(-1,3072),model.weight1)+model.bias1)*p).t()
    weight1_grad = torch.mm(data.view(-1,3072).t(),model.weight2.t()*p)
    bias1_grad = math.sqrt(1/width)*model.weight2.t()*p.view(-1,width)
    grad = torch.cat([weight1_grad.view(-1,3072*width),bias1_grad.view(-1,width),weight2_grad.view(-1,width)],dim=1)
    return grad
```

I am using CUDA to compute two matrices `kernel_tr` and `kernel_te`. The function `compute_layer_gradient` returns a `1*m` vector and `data_tr` and `data_te` are two matrices.

But the memory keeps increasing and I have tried using `del grad_tr_` or something like that but it doesn't work.

How to correctly release the memory in this loop?

Comment: Please include **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry I thought it was enough. The whole code is very large, so I upload the code of function.

Comment: The goal is generally for people to be able to run your code. This is particularly important since you haven’t shared any benchmarking/profiling data.

Comment: Did you try running this inside `with torch.no_grad()`? Does it also explode memory in that case?

Comment: Jatentaki thank you so much!!!! I am also wondering why it would compute the gradient.